# Dynamic dependency Injection in AKKA

Tags: dependency-injection, akka

I'd like to know if there is some pattern to handle dynamic dependency injection.

This concern the situation where we have supervision hierarchy. Let say I have a service Z that depend on a service c which is part of the a -> b -> c hierarchy.

Clearly Z does not own C, but would appreciate to use c.

It seems to me that Z needs to know that hierarchy in advance. In a sense that would defeat the all purpose of dependency injection. I don't want to couple Z to know that hierarchy. It may change in the future.

So I wonder how this kind of things work in general ?

I am thinking of using some configuration file, where this kind of information would be set. In other words, the architecture of the system would not be hardwire in the actor, but provided in a configuration, that the actor could use to request the service he needs.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost. Why can't you use normal dependency injection to give Z an reference to C?

Comment: Because C is created by B which is created by A. I don't have an ActorRef to C. Also imagine that C fault and that B stop it and re-creacte a new one, by supervision strategy, then Z needs to have the new actorRef.

Comment: Hence the dependency is intrinsically dynamic. Whenever you need to talk to an actor that is supervised and may fail and be recreated you have that dynamic dependency.

Comment: One way I manage a situation such as this is to give actors a type and then make use of an EventBus (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/event-bus.html) which allows interested actors to subscribe to listen for events for a specific "actor type". In your situation, C would publish it's type and ActorRef to the bus whenever it is created and Z would receive the message due it being subscribed to listen for type C actors.

Comment: If C is created before Z then you could switch this around so that as required Z puts a message on the bus saying it's interested in C actors. C can then subscribe to listen for these messages and respond to them as necessary to expose it's ActorRef to interested parties

Comment: Thanks for the EventBus tip. Can't the type be avoided here ? We are talking about typed actor right ?